# Actual Play of Don't Rest Your Head one-shot exemplar

Tags: system-introduction, session-summaries, dont-rest-your-head

I'm planning my first Don't Rest Your Head session for next weekend, and I'm feeling like I just don't get it yet. A solid one-session Actual Play recording of a Don't Rest Your Head game could really help me out here. Unfortunately I don't yet understand the qualities of DRYH that I'm hoping to learn, so I can't differentiate between good and bad examples.

**I'm asking for experts who understand DRYH well enough to judge the quality of a podcast and can give answers which explain how the linked content meets my needs.**

- Audio-only (podcast-style) is preferable, but a video works too. Text-only won't do unless there's a very good case for it otherwise.
- I want to experience a good model of the character creation process.
- I'm interested in seeing how the GM controls tension and escalation over the course of a one-shot campaign.
- The campaign doesn't need to stick to the Mad City setting (I'm not either), but I do want to see how an alternate version of the real world is used to push the storytelling.
- Some discussion of the mechanics as they come up in play would make me happy.

Answer (score 2):

Did some more digging and the actual play from [Role Playing Public Radio](http://actualplay.roleplayingpublicradio.com/2010/11/genre/modern-fantasy/dont-rest-your-head/) is a very good example of what you're looking for.

- Audio only (GM & three players)
- The first half hour is spent in creating the characters.
- Does stick to the Mad City

For me the tension & escalation felt right, but personal taste can differ here. The players seemed to like it. There is some mechanics discussion (GM & another player know the system, the others are new to it), but not much. Mostly done to briefly explain something to a player new to the system (why pain dominates,...). They did make some errors and they are explained in the comment section.

They have a [second one](http://actualplay.roleplayingpublicradio.com/2012/08/genre/horror/dont-rest-your-head-white-lightning-and-yellow-thunder/), but I haven't checked that one yet.

Comment: Thanks, but I could do a Google search on my own. I'm asking for people who have experience with DRYH to point me at Actual Play that demonstrates good practices in the game. If your recommendations do this, please edit your answer to explain it.

Comment: Let me re-phrase. I *have* done the Googles and am unable to differentiate between helpful and unhelpful Actual Plays, since I don't yet understand the qualities of DRYH that I'm hoping they'll teach me. You say the podcasts you recommend are "interesting," and the Stack's ["back it up" and "good subjective" principles](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/a/627/4398) ask you to support this claim somehow: why do you recommend those particular ones over all the others? (And for the record, the Stack also expects us to [be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).)